# jdbctemplate count queryForInt and pass multiple parameters

Tags: java, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

How can I pass multiple parameters in `jdbcTemplate` `queryForInt` to get the count. I have tried this,

```
Integer count = this.jdbcTemplate
    .queryForInt("select count(name) from table_name where parameter1 = ? and parameter2 = ?", new Object[]{parameter1,parameter2});
```

But its showing `queryForInt` as strikes.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Both queryForInt() and queryForLong() are deprecated since version 3.2.2 (correct me if mistake). To fix it, replace the code with queryForObject(String, Class).

```
 this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
                    sql, Integer.class, 
                    parameter1, parameter2);
```

As per [spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcTemplate.html)

> int   queryForInt(String sql, Map<String,?> args)

> **Deprecated**.
> Query for an int passing in a SQL query using the named parameter support provided by the NamedParameterJdbcTemplate and a map containing the arguments.

> int   queryForInt(String sql, Object... args)
> **Deprecated**.

> Query for an int passing in a SQL query using the standard '?' placeholders for parameters and a variable number of arguments.
> int queryForInt(String sql, SqlParameterSource args)
> Deprecated.
> Query for an int passing in a SQL query using the named parameter support provided by the NamedParameterJdbcTemplate and a SqlParameterSource containing the arguments.

Comment: Please mark the answer as ACCEPTED if it helped you to solve your problem. In this way it will help others looking for similar problem.

Comment: Edited this to include the current version with the whack-a-mole deprecation carousel. The current version is actually better as it uses a varargs syntax and moves the return type to the second argument.

Answer (score 7):

As per the current version of Spring Boot,

```
 this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
                sql, new Object[] { parameter1,parameter2 }, Integer.class);
```

is **deprecated**. So try the below given code:

```
 this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
                sql, Integer.class, new Object[] { parameter1,parameter2 });
```

Refer [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) Spring document.