# Check if a table exist in the SQL DB using JdbcTemplate and T-SQL

Tags: java, sql, t-sql, jdbctemplate

I am struggling with checking if a table exist in the DB. What I have done so far is as follows:

```
public boolean isTableExist(String tableName) {
    JdbcTemplate jdbc = getJdbcTemplate();
    String query =
        "IF (OBJECT_ID(?) IS NOT NULL ) "
            + "BEGIN "
            + "  PRINT 1 "
            + "  RETURN "
            + "END "
            + "ELSE "
            + "BEGIN "
            + "  PRINT 0 "
            + "  RETURN "
            + "END";

    Integer result = jdbc.queryForObject(query, Integer.class, tableName);
    return result == 1 ? true : false;
  }
```

Output (Error):

> PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [IF
>   (OBJECT_ID(?) IS NOT NULL ) BEGIN   PRINT 1   RETURN END ELSE BEGIN
>   PRINT 0   RETURN END]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; The statement
>   did not return a result set.; nested exception is
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not
>   return a result set.

Comment: Great job editing the answer with the solution. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, sir, for your help @zedfoxus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also run a query like so:

```
select count(*)
from information_schema.tables
where table_name = 'yourtablename'
    -- optionally this too
    -- and table_schema = 'dbo';
```

If you get zero, table doesn't exist.

Based on [jdbctemplate count queryForInt and pass multiple parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34216124/jdbctemplate-count-queryforint-and-pass-multiple-parameters) answer, it seems like you might have to use something like this once you store the query

```
jdbc.queryForObject(
    "select count(*) from information_schema.tables where table_name = ?"
    , new Object[] { tableName }
    , Integer.class
);
```

**Update:** 
The problem has been resolved with the help of this post and the final solution based on the above info is:

```
String query =
        "select count(*) "
            + "from information_schema.tables "
            + "where table_name = ? and table_schema = 'dbo'";
    Integer result = jdbc.queryForObject(query, Integer.class, tableName);
```